# Как вывести поле зарегистрированной таксономий в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

1) Зарегистрировал таксономию "Company"

```html
function company_taxonomy() {

 $labels = array(
  'name'                  => _x( 'Company', 'Taxonomy plural name', 'text-domain' ),
  'singular_name'         => _x( 'Company', 'Taxonomy singular name', 'text-domain' ),
  'search_items'          => __( 'Search Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'popular_items'         => __( 'Popular Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'all_items'             => __( 'All Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'update_item'           => __( 'Update Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'new_item_name'         => __( 'New SCompany', 'text-domain' ),
  'add_or_remove_items'   => __( 'Add or remove Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from most used Company', 'text-domain' ),
  'menu_name'             => __( 'Company', 'text-domain' ),
 );

 $args = array(
  'labels'            => $labels,
  'public'            => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
  'show_admin_column' => true,
  'hierarchical'      => false,
  'show_tagcloud'     => true,
  'show_ui'           => true,
  'query_var'         => true,
  'rewrite'           => true,
  'query_var'         => true,
  'capabilities'      => array(),
 );

 register_taxonomy( 'company', array( 'post' ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'company_taxonomy' );
```

2) В таксономий создал произвольные поля со slug-ми "company_name" и "company_logo" с помощью плагина ACF (Advanced custom gield).

Вопрос - как вывести значение этих полей?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: на моем примере можете показать? пробую по их рекомендаций, не получается.
$term = get_queried_object();
the_field('company_name', $term);

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода доп. полей термина нужно передать 2-м аргументом объект термина.

Подробнее: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Пример:

```
$term = get_queried_object();

the_field('company_name', $term);
the_field('company_logo', $term);
```

Comment: Нашел решение. Скорее не идаельное, но рабочее.

Comment: Код, который я скинул - рабочий)